# Any code examples for the Google Reader, or any API help?

Tags: java, delphi, google-reader

I could probably code quickest in Delphi - any examples?

Failing that, I guess it's time to dust off Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google hasn't officially released the api for Google Reader :(

However, people have used reverse engineering to come up with an unofficial documentation. Here is a simple tutorial -

http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

Visit

- [Martin Doms's Google Reader API – A Brief Tutorial](http://mindsharestrategy.com/2010/google-reader-api-a-brief-tutorial/)
- [Using the Google Reader API – Part 1](http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/)

However, you can see [unofficial documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI) of Google Reader API